# Representing "not" in lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

Is there any lambda function which takes as input a lambda term $\lambda x_1x_2...x_n.f$ which is a function of $n$ variables and produces, $\lambda x_1x_2...x_n.\sim f$ . $\sim$ denotes "not". If we know the value of $n$, we can come up with the desired function easily.

Example:
$n=2$.
Desired function is : $\lambda px_1x_2.\sim p@x_1@x_2$ which will do this operation.
$\lambda x_1x_2.f(x_1,y_1) ->  \lambda x_1x_2.\sim f(x_1,y_1)$

I am looking for a for a lambda function which can do this operation and which does not change depending on the value of n.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your question doesn't have much sens, as P is itself a lambda term, so you define "not" ($\neg$) as $\neg\lambda x.y\rightarrow \lambda x.\neg y$. Many definitions follow this property, like the identity for example.

Comment: what i tried to mean is f (or P, i just edited) does not have any more lambda inside it.